# Support validation of partial data using ANTLR

Tags: validation, antlr3

I am fairly new to ANTLR and have some basic understanding of ANTLR is used to validate a input.But some how i am failing to fulfill my requirement.
My requirement basically is to validate a part of complete string.
my input would be divided in 4 sections header, Student data,school Data, footer.
Sample Data would be as

HEADER,MYDATA
STUDENT,NAME,ROLLNO
SCHOOL,NAME,ADDRESS
STUDENT,NAME,ROLLNO
SCHOOL,NAME,ADDRESS
FOOTER

HEADER,SCHOOL,STUDENT will be different tokens

Grammar file would be common.
each section would come via a different process. How can i validate for example, only header details based on the ANTLR grammar and so on only details of student,school and Footer ???

If i only pass partial data (Example Header data) as input via ANTLRStringStream, it fails with NoViableException.

Answer (score 1):

If in your grammar, you have separate rules for validating each section individually, like

```
completeData: header studentData schoolData footer;

/* Rule for matching header part */
header: something something;
/* and so on for other sections */
```

You could call these rules instead of calling the rule for completeData. And you would need to give appropriate partial input (like just the header part).

The code would be something like.

```
try {
    MyLexer lexer = new MyLexer (new ANTLRStringStream (myInputString));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream (lexer);
    MyParser parser = new MyParser (tokens);

    parser.header ();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace ();
}
```